# Converting a string into a JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following string:

```
[{"EventType":1,"ParticipantId":"1","X":123,"Y":123},{"EventType":2,"ParticipantId":"1","ParrentList":[123,124,125,126],"X":0,"Y":0}]
```

Could anybody give me an idea on how to convert this into a JSON structure and then get the value of each key, say:

```
EventType = 1;
ParticipantId = 1;
X = 123;
etc.
```

I'm actually trying to do it as follows, but I don't think that this is a smart way of doing that:

```
var results = [{"EventType":1,"ParticipantId":"1","X":123,"Y":123},{"EventType":2,"ParticipantId":"1","ParrentList":[123,124,125,126],"X":0,"Y":0}];  
  var arr = eval("(" + results + ')');

    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        var obj = arr[i];
            for(var key in obj) {
            var attrName = key;
            var attrValue = obj[key];

              switch(attrName) {
               case "EventType" :
                   EventType = attrValue;
               break;
               case "ParticipantId" :
                   ParticipantId = attrValue;
               break;
               case "X" :
                   xCoord = attrValue;         
               break;
               case "Y" :
                   yCoord = attrValue;
                       break;

                 }
                    }
                  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: That already is JSON... I don't get what you're trying to do: where does this code come from?

Comment: The code is actually returned from an ASP.NET WebMethod which returns a string. If I pass that string directly, without eval(), I will not be able to parse it as a JSON object.

Comment: So it's retrieved by AJAX, not by a simple `var results =` assignment in your Javascript?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, it's retrieved by an AJAX call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a Javascript object. So you could just do:

```
for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var result = results[i];

    var eventType = result.EventType;
    var participantId = result.ParticipantId;
    var xCoord = result.X;
    var yCoord = result.Y;

    ...
}
```

There is no need to iterate over the properties and there is most certainly no reason to use `eval` in this case either. Javascript already recognizes your variable as an object.

Now if results was an actual string, I recommend using [`JSON.parse(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON#Parsing_JSON.C2.A0strings) to get back a Javascript object:

```
var results = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON.parse is your friend.

But yes... I am also confused. In your sample you already have JSON. You only need to parse it if you need to convert from a string to an object.

Answer (score 0):

> Could anybody give me an idea on how to convert this into a JSON structure and then get the value of each key

Point 1: this *is* a JSON structure. JSON is a notation for serialising data to transfer across the internet (or for other storage/transfer purposes, but this is the important one). JSON-encoded data *is* a string. Always.  JSON notation strongly resembles (indeed, is entirely compatible with) the notation for objects in Javascript itself.

What you *actually* want to do is to convert a string of JSON-encoded data into a Javascript object.  The relevant function is [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var data = JSON.parse(results);
```

You can then access the data in the normal way, e.g. `data[0].EventType` will be `1`. I'm not sure what you mean by "get the value of each key", since the data is an array of similarly-structured objects, so there are multiple values for each key.